# Asynchronous Angular Promise and Variable Initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

I have a factory that looks like such:

```
app.factory('thingFactory', function($http) {

    var factory = {};   
    var things = [];

    factory.refreshThings = function() {
        return $http.post('/GetThings');
    }

    factory.initializeThings = factory.refreshThings()
        .then(function(response) {
            things = response.data;
        }, function(response){
            // some error handling code here...
        });

    factory.getThings = function() {
        return things;
    }

    return factory;
}
```

and a controller

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, thingFactory) {
    $scope.things = thingFactory.getThings();
}
```

Because of the asynchronous nature of promises, and other collections being initialized (in addition to `things`), should I be concerned with `getThings()` returning an empty array, and thus, returning before the `$http.post()` call has resolved?

Is this a better alternative?

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, thingFactory) {
    $scope.things = []

    thingFactory.initializeThings
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.things = response.data;
        }, function (response) {
            // some error handling code here...
        });
}
```

Is there a safe alternative, where I can get the controller to not think about the promise and just safely get the collection from the factory?

Comment: Why not just make `getThings` return a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is definitely going to be problematic. The factory will not be instantiated until it is used by a controller, so `things` will not be initialized until it is called by a controller, at which time `initializeThings` will get called right before you call `getThings`, which will likely return an empty array. Also, it's never a good idea to follow a "let's hope it's there" approach.

I see two approaches you can take: `getThings` accepts a callback as an argument or it returns a promise, which could look something like this:

1. Callbacks - I prefer callbacks over promises, but that's a personal thing. Also, I use NodeJS-inspired syntax:

   ```
   var things; // no need to initialize array

   // callback -> function (error, things) {}
   factory.getThings = function (callback) {
     if (things) {
       return callback(null, things);
     }

     factory.refreshThings()
       .then( function (response) {
           things = response.data;
           return callback(null, things);
       }, function (reason) {
           return callback(reason);
       });
   }
   ```
2. Promises - not the best syntax, but you get the idea

   ```
   factory.getThings = function () {
     var d = $q.defer();
     // I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but setting
     // this in a timeout will allow the promise to return so that
     // you can try to return it.
     $timeout( function () {
       if (things) {
          return d.resolve(things);
       }

       factory.refreshThings()
         .then( function (response) {
           things = response.data;
           return d.resolve(things);
         }, function (reason) {
           return d.reject(reason);
         });
     });

     return d.promise;
   }
   ```

As a side note, if you're using a RESTful API, GET should be used to get information rather than POST.